# Convert UK DATE to MySQL date?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I convert UK date to mySQL Date?

For example I select a date from a calender: 07/06/2011

Now I want it to conver it to YYYY-MM-DD so I can use it in the WHERE query?

Comment: Reference: mySQL: [Date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: This will work: [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
STR_TO_DATE($date,'%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want a PHP solution:

```
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dmy)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT STR_TO_DATE('$myDate','%d/%m/%Y') FROM MyTable";
```